# Free app licensing - Could it be creative commons?

Tags: licensing

I am creating a free nokia application for which I am about to use images from a creative common website. Now my question is if a free application come under creative commons as it is not a paid one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different creative commons options:
But I think a free app by an individual developer comes under"non-commercial"

There is also an attributions clause, so you might have to mention the source of the icons in the description